# $2 \lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor 2x \rfloor \leq 2 \lfloor x \rfloor +1$

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

May I know the standard proof technique to prove such kind of inequalities.

$2 \lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor 2x \rfloor \leq 2 \lfloor x \rfloor +1$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What is $\lfloor 2x\rfloor$, when A) $x$ is in the interval $[n,n+1/2)$, B) when $x$ is in the interval $[n+1/2,n+1)$?

Comment: Floor(x) = x - frac(x) may help.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976665/show-that-0-leq-left-lfloor-frac2ab-right-rfloor-2-left-lfloor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Hermite's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity), we know that $ \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor \le \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x + \frac 12 \rfloor = \lfloor 2x \rfloor \le \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor$. Alternatively, as already mentioned, you can use casework on $\{x\} := x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, in particular when $0 \le \{x\} < 1/2$ and when $1/2 \le \{x\} < 1$.

Comment: Hermite's Identity is a nice way to solve this. Thanks. But I am not able to understand the other method..

Comment: I can get case 1 when $0 \le \{x\} < 1/2$. but am not able grasp the other case..

Comment: I'd imagine you figured it out by now, but suppose $x = n + r$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1/2 \le r < 1$. Then $2\lfloor x \rfloor = 2n, \lfloor 2x \rfloor = 2n+1, 2\lfloor x \rfloor + 1 = 2n+1$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: let $n = \lfloor{x\rfloor}$, so $n \le x < n+1$.  What about $2x$?